# Recording sounds straight from sound card

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I'm trying to record sounds straight from my sound card. I've found tutorials telling me to download PulseAudio Video Control and, in the "Recording" tab, make sure that I am recording from "Monitor of Internal Audio Analog Stereo". However, I can't find any options for this. I've only "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo".

I'm guessing this is a hardware issue but is there any chance there is just some driver I have to download? Are there any other options for me to be able to record sounds straight from my sound card?

Answer (score 0):

here is a quick and dirty way I've used in the past based on the following [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1330728)

First you need to get a little script and make sure you have a sound utility installed...

```
cd ~ ; mkdir bin ;cd bin
sudo apt-get install sox
wget http://outflux.net/software/pa-clone
chmod u+x pa-clone ;cd ~
```

Now, record something and press CRTL-C to stop :

```
 pa-clone output.wav
```